# Bash: count occurrences of a char in all files of folder

Tags: bash

I need to count occurrences of a char in all files of folder. I am using this script:

```
TEMPFILE=/tmp/1.tmp
echo 0 > $TEMPFILE
y=0
cat $TEMPFILE
for file in `find -name "*.*"`
do
   grep -o c $file | y=$(cat $TEMPFILE)+$(wc -l);
   echo $y > $TEMPFILE 

done

echo $(cat $TEMPFILE)
```

But the value of y is always 0. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** Misunderstood the question :)

Try this, it should work:

```
find /etc/  -type f -print0| xargs  -0  grep -o  c | wc -l
```

PS. replace /etc/ for whatever folder you like

Comment: Your method is broken for filenames that contain spaces or newlines. This kind of mistake is so common that it's not even funny anymore. The standard cure is to use the `-print0` option of `find` with the `-0` option of `xargs`. Dear, this is so common that maybe you should document yourself before posting answers.

Comment: Thanks @gniourf_gniourf, it's good to learn something new. If I wasn't posting answers I would certainly miss that :)

Comment: Then you don't need `xargs` really, find will gladly execute `grep` for you: `find /etc/ -type f -exec grep -o c {} \; | wc -l`

Answer (score 2):

One possibility to count the number of a given character in a file is to delete all the other characters and count the remaining ones. `tr` is a good choice for this:

```
tr -cd X < file
```

will only output the characters `X` from file `file`. Then to count the number of `X` in file `file`:

```
tr -cd X < file | wc -m
```

For several files, using `find` and no external arithmetic:

```
find . -type f -exec cat {} + | tr -cd X | wc -m
```

The trick here is to have `find` spit out the content of all files with `-exec cat {} +` and then do the filtering with `tr` and the counting with `wc`.

Answer (score 1):

> But the value of y is always 0. Why?

Whenever you connect multiple commands using pipes `|`, each command is run in a *subshell*, meaning that it gets a separate copy of the execution environment (variables, shell functions, working directory, and so on). So when you assign something to `y` inside one of the commands in a pipeline, you're actually assigning something to a *copy* of `y` — a separate variable named `y` that the surrounding script can never see.

There are some other problems with your script as well, but that's the main one.

To be honest, it's probably simplest to dispense with the variable `y`, as well as the temporary file, and just use `grep`'s `--recursive` flag to have it search the whole directory for you. Then all you need to do is pipe its output to `wc -l` to count the occurrences it finds. Your whole script can be written as:

```
grep -o --recursive -h c . | wc -l
```